# Hard Error: SMTP -> FROM SERVER:421 Unexpected failure, please try later

Tags: php, ssl, smtp, phpmailer

I look lots of solution pages but I can't solve this problem.I don't understand why happened this,because everything is perfect when I use it yesterday.Please help me :(

Note: I only a webpage admin,not server admin

!!!! You can see my codes and download here --> http://s2.dosya.tc/server/6vnkfc/codes.rar.html

My logs:

```html
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220-nserver75.emikrondns.com ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1 Tue, 14 Jun 2016 00:22:22 +0300 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220-nserver75.emikrondns.com ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1 Tue, 14 Jun 2016 00:22:22 +0300 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "220-nserver75.emikrondns.com ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1 Tue, 14 Jun 2016 00:22:22 +0300 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220-nserver75.emikrondns.com ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1 Tue, 14 Jun 2016 00:22:22 +0300 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "220-nserver75.emikrondns.com ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1 Tue, 14 Jun 2016 00:22:22 +0300 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 and/or bulk e-mail. " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220-nserver75.emikrondns.com ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1 Tue, 14 Jun 2016 00:22:22 +0300 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail. " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220-nserver75.emikrondns.com ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1 Tue, 14 Jun 2016 00:22:22 +0300 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail. 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-nserver75.emikrondns.com Hello gorselsozluk.com [37.247.96.230] " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-nserver75.emikrondns.com Hello gorselsozluk.com [37.247.96.230] " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-nserver75.emikrondns.com Hello gorselsozluk.com [37.247.96.230] " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 52428800 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-nserver75.emikrondns.com Hello gorselsozluk.com [37.247.96.230] 250-SIZE 52428800 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-nserver75.emikrondns.com Hello gorselsozluk.com [37.247.96.230] 250-SIZE 52428800 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-nserver75.emikrondns.com Hello gorselsozluk.com [37.247.96.230] 250-SIZE 52428800 250-8BITMIME " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-nserver75.emikrondns.com Hello gorselsozluk.com [37.247.96.230] 250-SIZE 52428800 250-8BITMIME " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-nserver75.emikrondns.com Hello gorselsozluk.com [37.247.96.230] 250-SIZE 52428800 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-nserver75.emikrondns.com Hello gorselsozluk.com [37.247.96.230] 250-SIZE 52428800 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-nserver75.emikrondns.com Hello gorselsozluk.com [37.247.96.230] 250-SIZE 52428800 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-nserver75.emikrondns.com Hello gorselsozluk.com [37.247.96.230] 250-SIZE 52428800 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 HELP " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-nserver75.emikrondns.com Hello gorselsozluk.com [37.247.96.230] 250-SIZE 52428800 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250 HELP " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-nserver75.emikrondns.com Hello gorselsozluk.com [37.247.96.230] 250-SIZE 52428800 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250 HELP 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "235 Authentication succeeded " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "235 Authentication succeeded " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 OK " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250 OK " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 OK 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 Accepted " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250 Accepted " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 Accepted 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "421 Unexpected failure, please try later " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "421 Unexpected failure, please try later " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:421 Unexpected failure, please try later 
SMTP -> ERROR: DATA not accepted from server: 421 Unexpected failure, please try later 
SMTP Error: Data not accepted.
```

Comment: Do you think share your codes with us ? Because error output isn't helpful for you

Comment: Ivan is right - but a wild guess is that you have not obeyed the SMTP command ordering constraints - that is, which commands can occur at what point. That said, unless you are doing this for educational purposes, go find a well supported library that does it for you. SMTP is a very demanding thing to do right in all cases and broken implementations abound, which means you will need to work around those implementations in your code without becoming another one for everyone else to work around.

Comment: @IvanBarayev  You can see my codes and download here -> http://s2.dosya.tc/server/6vnkfc/codes.rar.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 421 Unexpected failure, please try later

This is a temporary problem on the server side and like it says you should try later. Reason for this kind of error might be a full disk at the mail server or some limitation how much mails you allowed to send within a specific time or similar.

If the problem remains you need to contact the provider of the mail server and ask to explain or to fix the problem.